# Why does DateTime.ParseExact throw an exception when parsing this literal string?

Tags: c#, datetime

This code snippet generates an exception:

```
string t = @"11\10\2023"; 
string _fmt = @"MM\dd\yyyy"; 

DateTime l = DateTime.ParseExact(t, _fmt, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Exception is:

> System.FormatException
> HResult=0x80131537
> Message=String '' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
> Source=System.Private.CoreLib
> StackTrace:
> at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider)

Why is that?

Comment: I'm not aware of anywhere that uses backslashes in dates. Should those actually be forward slashes, like basically everyone else uses?

Comment: @jmcilhinney: That's not what "everyone else" uses. Plenty of cultures use period or dash. But more importantly, the OP may not have control of the format they're being asked to parse. I'd agree that where possible, it would be good to not use a backslash - but if the OP has control, I'd normally prefer to use an ISO format instead of *just* changing to a forward slash.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I realise that some cultures use dots or dashes. I meant that every culture that I'm aware of that uses slashes uses forward slashes, not backslashes. I understand that the OP may not be in control of the format. That's why I asked a question, rather than making a statement.

Answer (score 7):

Your format string uses backslashes. Within a [custom format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#Literals), a backslash is used to escape the next character, so your format string is expecting input such as `"11d10y123"` (which will parse as valid).

If you want the backslash to be treated literally, you need to escape it by putting in a double backslash:

```cs
string _fmt = @"MM\\dd\\yyyy";
```

Note that this *isn't* a C#-language-level escaping. That string really does contain double backslashes, because that's what you want to pass to `DateTime.ParseExact`.

(I'd note that using backslashes as a separator like this is unusual. If you're in control of the format, I'd recommend using forward slashes, or - my strong preference when I have a choice - following ISO-8601 with a format such as `yyyy-MM-dd` which not only avoids slashes of all kinds, but also removes the "month first vs day first" ambiguity. Of course you may not have any control of the value you're parsing.)

Comment: Jon,

Thank you, your solution works. It will take me some time to understand why '@' symbol, when applied to format, does still require 'double backslash'. As an experiment, I tried this format, expecting it to work, and it does.
_fmt = "MM\\\\dd\\\\yyyy"

Still, the understanding 'why' escapes me. Format string defines the placement of the separator and separator itself. The string correctly specify format and separator, single backslash... It will take time for me to understand. 

Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelEstrinOne: The `@` sign is only about the *C# language* escaping of the backslash. The extra level of escaping is because in the format string specifier itself, backslash is *also* an escape symbol, so needs to be escaped if you want an actual backslash in the effective pattern. (A bit like for regular expressions, if that helps.)

Comment: Jon, very helpful indeed. Thank you for clarifications!